# why windows title not set on jQuery ui window?

Tags: jquery

i load a view on popup window it works fine but window title not set and is empty always but i set it in my code it runs without error.
what is wrong with me?

```
$(function () {

$(".dialog-trigger").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "OpenSendSmsDialog",
        type: "GET",
    })
    .done(function (result) {
        $("#clientdetailmodal").html(result).dialog({
            autoOpen: true, width: 400, modal: true, show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            }
        }, "option", "title", "321 file");
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing random arguments after the object used to initialize the dialog, they simply get ignored: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
    $("#clientdetailmodal").html(result).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        title: '321 file'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the DOC:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ title: "Dialog Title" });
```

OR:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "title", "Dialog Title" );
```

So here, you could use:

```
 $("#clientdetailmodal").html(result).dialog({
            autoOpen: true, width: 400, modal: true, show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000

            },title: '321 file' 
        });
```

Comment: I think the indentation confused you there, the title must be outside the innermost closing curly brace: `show: { ... }, title: '321 file'`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the title option like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true, width: 400, modal: true, show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        }, title: "321 file" });
```